# Create index of a reference genome with bwa and gatk using snakemake touch

Tags: snakemake

I align reads with `bwa` and call variants with `gatk`. `gatk` needs the creation of a `dict` for the reference genome, and `bwa` needs creation of indices. When I use touch for both of them I get this error:

```
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules bwa_index and gatk_refdict are ambiguous for the file ref.
Expected input files:
        bwa_index: ref.fasta
        gatk_refdict: ref.fasta
```

This is the code:

```
rule bwa_index:
    input:
        database="ref.fasta"
    output:
        done =touch("ref")
    shell:
        """
        bwa index -p ref {input.database}
        """
rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        bwa_index_done = "ref",
        fastq1="{sample}_R1.trimmed.fastq.gz",
        fastq2="{sample}_R2.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = temp("{sample}.bam")
    shell:
        """
        bwa mem ref {input.fastq1} {input.fastq2} -o {output.bam}
        """
rule_gatk_refdict:
    input:
        ref="ref.fasta"
    output:
        done =touch("ref")
    shell:
        """
        java -jar gatk-package-4.1.9.0-local.jar CreateSequenceDictionary -R {input.ref} -O {output.done}
        """
rule gatk:
    input:
        gatk_refdict_done = "ref",
        bam="bam_list"
    output:
        outf ="{chr}.vcf"
    shell:
        """
        java -jar gatk-package-4.1.9.0-local.jar HaplotypeCaller -L {wildcards.chr} -R ref -I {input.bam} --min-base-quality-score 20 -O {output.outf}
        """
```

Alternatively, I am specifing the index `.dict`, but then it doesn't work neither, because gatk calls variants before creating dict and so I get an error that there is no dict file:

```
rule_gatk_refdict:
    input:
        ref="ref.fasta"
    output:
        outf ="ref.dict"
    shell:
        """
        java -jar gatk-package-4.1.9.0-local.jar CreateSequenceDictionary -R {input.ref} -O {output.outf}
        """
rule gatk:
    input:
        ref = "ref.fasta",
        bam="bam_list"
    output:
        outf ="{chr}.vcf"
    shell:
        """
        java -jar gatk-package-4.1.9.0-local.jar HaplotypeCaller -L {wildcards.chr} -R {input.ref} -I {input.bam} --min-base-quality-score 20 -O {output.outf}
        """
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply define the `dict` file as an input of the gatk rule and the ìndex as an input of the bwa rule?

```
rule bwa_index:
    input:
        database="ref.fasta"
    output:
        done =touch("ref")
    shell:
        """
        bwa index -p ref {input.database}
        """
rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        bwa_index_done = "ref",
        fastq1="{sample}_R1.trimmed.fastq.gz",
        fastq2="{sample}_R2.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = temp("{sample}.bam")
    shell:
        """
        bwa mem ref {input.fastq1} {input.fastq2} -o {output.bam}
        """
rule gatk_refdict:
    input:
        ref="ref.fasta"
    output:
        done = "ref.dict"
    shell:
        """
        java -jar gatk-package-4.1.9.0-local.jar CreateSequenceDictionary -R {input.ref} -O {output.done}
        """
rule gatk:
    input:
        ref = "ref.fasta",
        dict = "ref.dict",
        bam="bam_list"
    output:
        outf ="{chr}.vcf"
    shell:
        """
        java -jar gatk-package-4.1.9.0-local.jar HaplotypeCaller -L {wildcards.chr} -R {input.ref} -I {input.bam} --min-base-quality-score 20 -O {output.outf}
        """
```

The `AmbiguousRuleException` you get is because snakemake doesn't know which rule to run since two rules have the same output.  Don't forget snakemake tries to build the DAG starting from the rule all. When it comes to run `rule gatk`, you define `"ref"` as an input. Since two rules can produce this file, snakemake does not known weither it must use `rule gatk_refdict` or `rule bwa_index`.

You have a typo there ("_" that should not be there):

```
----v
rule_gatk_refdict:
    input:
        ref="ref.fasta"
    ...
```

Comment: because actually in rule gatk as input it wants the original ref.fasta file and not dict, which is just an index file. Generally, it the next rule doesn't have as input the output of the previous rule, the pipeline doesnt work...

Comment: oh yes, I corrected the typo error, thanks :) but the problem remains...

Comment: The creation of the dict file and the bwa index are two independent processes. They can be run in parallel. Even if both rules need the same input `ref.fasta`, they can be run independently

Comment: ok, that is clear, but for example see my alternative solution where I specify .dict extention. Rule gatk_refdict has ref.fasta as input and rule gatk also needs ref.fasta as input, the rule gatk woud be run before rule gatk_refdict, which is why it cannot find a dict extention...same problem for samtools as I added above...how to solve this?

Comment: Nope, if you define `ref.dict` in rule gatk, it will force snakemake to run rule gatk_refdict before. If you need `ref.fasta` in rule gatk, just put it in input too. See my upcoming EDIT